# SSD for Ubuntu and Which folders could I locate them on SSD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, directory, performance

I have a small SSD, and it does not enough to put whole of UBUNTU OS (of course I excepted /home folder already, I always set it up on a separate partition on HDD) on the SSD, while I want to have best performance in SSD condition I have.

Thus, I want to ask mr/ms that, which folders of Ubuntu should I mount on HDD instead of SSD

(Should /var, /tmp, /user???)

ps/ I am a basic ubuntu user, and I don't know the detail of method ubuntu operating

Update information of my system:

- RAM: 8GB
- CPU: Intel Corei5-41xx
- GPU/ VGA: integrated-GPU/ non-external-VGA
- SSD: 80 GB (I only reserved 10 - 15 GB for improving performance of Ubuntu)
- HDD: 500 GB (7200 RPM)
- Dual-boot (windows10 and linux)
- All my harddisks is using GPT as scheme.

Best regard,

Thanks

Comment: How many GB is your SSD ? And in general what are the specs of your computer ?

Comment: Edit your question and add some information about the hardware setup like: what is the size of RAM and SSD, what is your partition scheme (MBR or GPT), do you have another operating system on this computer, etc. That will be helpful in addressing specifically to your problem. For a general answer refer to this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/89230), it is one possible solution to your question.

Comment: Ubuntu base takes 10Gb so how small is your disk to be this to be a problem? Add a few Gb more for comfort but no more then 25Gb and even that should be twice what you need) I would say: no directories. Just switch your directories in /home to another location (see the file `~./config/user-dirs.dirs` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A linux installation after a few months of usage will show major [disk space](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace#More_Complex_Schemes) usage shares in `/usr`, `/var`, `/lib` and `/opt`, where `/usr` is the most demanding filesystem that may span 60-70% of the `root filesystem`. Hence to speed up your system while keeping SSD wear to minimum, place your `/var`, `/tmp`, `/home` and `swap` on a spinning disk. You can place rest of the `root filesystem` tree (should you choose a single `/` or divide it in `/boot`, `/` and `/usr`) on the SSD.

Another important factor would be the reason to install Linux. If you are just interested in learning the operating system and you are not planning to install a lot of applications, a 15 GB of SSD partition should suffice. Here I would recommend you to consider different [Ubuntu flavors](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/flavours) that require less disk space and provide a good desktop experience e.g. Xubuntu or Lubuntu.